# Fraunhofer lines during an eclipse

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation, spectroscopy, eclipse

I  know that Fraunhofer lines are certain wavelengths in the Sun's spectrum that are 'missing' because of absorption at the chromosphere. In other words, they are 'dark'.
But my book clearly states that they are strangely 'brighter'(?!)during a total solar eclipse. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

The Fraunhofer lines are not produced by absorption in the chromosphere, they are produced by absorption in the photosphere.

The chromosphere is a hotter, *optically thin* region, that lies above the photosphere. During a total solar eclipse we can see the chromosphere but not the photosphere. Because the chromosphere is optically thin, any radiation produced by downward transitions, like H$\alpha$, can travel freely from the Sun and is observed as emission lines.

We can only see this during an eclipse because the chromosphere emits much less light than the photosphere and so there is a contrast problem, unless you observe through a filter that picks out an emission line.

Comment: That explains it well. Thank you!

Comment: Emission lines later attributed to helium have first been noticed by Pogson, during an eclipse in India. As I understand, helium absorption lines from the solar photosphere are difficult to observe. If that's correct, is it because the peak in a graph of the ionized fraction of helium atoms, combining the Boltzmann distribution and the Saha equation, occurs at a much higher temperature than 5772K? Do O/B stars have helium absorption lines in the photosphere spectrum?